# Dropwizard ObjectMapper not honouring enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS)

Tags: java, enums, dropwizard, jackson-databind

I want to be able for jackson to parse case insensitive enums. For e.g

```
public enum OperType {
  SUM
  PRODUCT
}
```

i want to accept both "SUM" and "sum" in the POST request.

I am getting hold of objectMapper in Application::run and enabling the setting:

```
environment.getObjectMapper().enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);
```

But this is having no effect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey doesn't use objectMapper from Dropwizard bootstrap despite what Dropwizard's official documentation might lead one to believe.
Needed to register custom ContextResolver in the Application::run to make it work:

```
environment.jersey().register(new ObjectMapperContextResolver(injector.getInstance(ObjectMapper.class)));
```

where:

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

}
```

Man these documentations around the dropwizard ecosystem can be really confusing for someone who isn't as well versed yet!